# Why do applications I install only sometimes appear in the Applications directory?

Tags: macos, applications

This is on OSX 10.7.5.

Often when I install a new application it wont appear in the Applications folder and the only way I can access it is by using Spotlight.

Any way I can make all applications appear in this folder?

Comment: Where do they end up? The same place or different locations each time? How are you installing these applications, using the Installer app from Apple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its the **path** of the installer. Most will automatically download in *Applications*.
Notice how at the end of most installers, the finder window pops up with only its contents, and a **symlink** to your *Applications* folder for you to drag & drop into it.
 If an application does not follow that installation structure, its because the developer **didn't** invest the time to do so.